# NGINX: serve static file when proxy_pass fails

Tags: nginx

I have a frontend running nginx which proxy requests to a backend running a web service.
I would like to serve a static file if the backend service is down.

Here is the configuration file I am using:

```
location ~ /api/admin {
        rewrite /xxxx/(.+) /$1 break;
        error_page 404 502 =200 /themes/yyyy/themes.json;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST';
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass http://xxxx;
}

location = /themes/yyyy/themes.json {
        rewrite /themes/yyyy/themes.json /api/admin/thematics/edito;
}
```

when I call :

```
http://url/themes/geoportail/themes.json
```

I receive a 502 error from nginx, instead of 200 and the static file...

```
2014/08/25 17:02:35 [error] 13551#0: *6719 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 160.92.103.160, server: uri, request: "GET /themes/yyyy/themes.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://IP:PORT/api/admin/thematics/edito", host: "", referrer: ""
```

Comment: nope, I'll read the manuel and try that

Comment: Ok, I tried recursive_error_pages, that does not help. I get internal error: *6950 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing

Comment: If you wnat static file, why you do a rewrite?

Comment: that's a good question, that's not my file, trying to debug it... How would you just send a specific file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm posting a solution I've found, feel free to propose something more elegant.

```
location ~ /api/admin {
        rewrite /xxxx/(.+) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST';
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass http://xxxx;
        error_page 404 502 503 504 =200 @statictheme;
}

location @statictheme {
    try_files $uri /themes/yyyy/themes.json last;
}

location = /themes/yyyy/themes.json {
        rewrite /themes/yyyy/themes.json /api/admin/thematics/edito;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre Mélard, this helped greatly. In my setup, I'm proxying security cameras, but if they are offiline, a static image will show instead. The `error_page 504 ...` and `try_files ...` were the key pieces that made it work. I also added `proxy_connect_timeout 2s;` to the main location block as well.

Comment: The most confounding factor for me was the need for `last` in the `try_files ...` block. The Nginx docs didn't provide that clue.

Comment: ----> dope! <-----